# Is it possible for NSWindow to close from full screen mode without animation?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I would like my full screen window to close quickly without animations. I have tried to set animationBehavior to NSWindowAnimationBehaviorNone, but it did not help.
Is there a way to close a full screen NSWindow without animation?

Comment: Do you want it to close or exit fullscreen? Title and description indicate different behavior?

Comment: I have updated the title to match. It would be nice to exit full screen mode without animation too, but my primary goal is to close (orderOut) the window.